# ISDEV fatal error 1027 Failed signing .tmp with SINGLE_EXE_IMAGE signing disabled

Tags: installshield, installshield-2015

Once the ism project file is loaded in the InstallShield, under the [Installation Designer] Media->Releases for SINGLE_EXE_IMAGE I have Signing disabled by selecting None option for "Sign Output Files" and No for "Sign Files in Package" (under the Signing tab).

However, ewvery time I try to build the ism project I get a "Failed signing ***.tmp" error with code 1027 and *** is a different file name with every build.

I know that this error appears if the certificate file is not up-to-date or other reasons, but I have the signing deactivated at all, why do I still get this?

Comment: I have the exact same problem.
Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not really, have it parked.

Answer (score 0):

open project, go to MEDIA -> Releases -> Core then open Signing tab and remove whatever content you have in "***Digital Certificate Information***" this field and give a try.